# most accurate data type for positioning

Tags: c#, math, xna, monogame

This is something that has been very annoying. In XNA/Monogame, SpriteBatch.Draw uses either a Vector2 for position, or a Rectangle for position. Vector2 accepts float values, while Rectangles only take in ints.

I need to use floats/doubles because they support smooth movement of images across the screen. However I've noticed specific math errors when doing things that require Cosine and Sine, Truncate, or any of the math conversion functions.

Take this formula for example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{

creategraphic(320+64*cos(360/8*i),240*+64*sin(360/8*i));

}
```

This should create 8 textures, on a circle with a radius of 64, and are evenly spaced. The result however, is nowhere near that. I get values that have objects spawning from the same angle or something even worse.

So for positioning, what is the best way to handle it when working with complex math calculations and still retain accuracy?

Comment: You should replace `360` by `360.0f` for a start.

Comment: I tried that, but the angles are still wrong. No noticeable change.
http://s9.postimg.org/4jyrylmsv/Screenshot_70.png a picture of what I'm getting, even after adding .0f to 360

Comment: sin/cos usually take radians (not degrees like in your code). Not sure what language/library you are using so don't know if it applies.

Comment: Ah wow, I had completely forgot to do that. I'm transitioning from a scripting engine that does that for us. Maybe I'll create a duplicate that works with degrees. Thanks for solving this. I was using C# btw

Answer (score 0):

Like Alexei said the trigonometric functions use Radians as opposed to Degrees.  XNA has a helper class that can accomplish the conversions you need:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.mathhelper.toradians.aspx